# Выбрать существующую таблицу SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Как после создания таблицы в SQLite Database, выбрать ее для вставки?

Или нужно будет писать такой же код, просто без `names.create(engine)`?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Integer, String, Column

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')

meta = MetaData()

names = Table('names', meta,
              Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column('name', String(60))
              )
names.create(engine)


ins = names.insert().values(id=1, name='Vasya')

connection = engine.connect()
res = connection.execute(ins)
res.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Так вы же уже написали правильный запрос? Документация по [insert](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert)

```
ins = names.insert().values(id=1, name='Vasya')
```

Пример 1:

```
stmt = names.insert().values(id=1, name='vasya')
db.execute(stmt)
```

Результат:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:(1, 'vasya')
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
```

Пример 2:

```
stmt = insert(table=names).values(id=2, name='petya')
db.execute(stmt)
```

Результат:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:(2, 'petya')
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
```